# C++ std::vector initialised and set within header file

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, header-files

I'm currently having some issues trying to implement std::vectors in my code over using arrays, in my header file.

I've searched through StackOverflow and Google for the past 1h 30m, and cannot find anything helpful.

Simply put, I have been using an array that has been initialised and set within a header file. Converting this code using `std::vector`s has caused some issues.

I am doing my project analysis in (cern) ROOT, which uses a lot of `typedef`'s which are obvious, *e.g.*, `Int_t` ==> `int`.

One of the header files imported automatically calls `using namespace std;`, therefore I have just left off all the `std::` namespaces.

Currently I have:

```
// file.h
// ...
const Int_t kNpdgCodes = 14;

Int_t pdgCodeID[kNpdgCodes] = {
        0, // other
       22, // photon
      111, // pi0
     -211, // pim
      211, // pip
      221, // eta
      130, // K0L
      310, // K0s
     -321, // Km
      321, // Kp
    -2112, // (a)n
     2112, // n
     2212, // p
     3122  // Lambda
};
// ...
```

I'm trying to get it in the form (or nicer, as there is no useful = constructor [cannot use C++11]):

```
// file.h
// ...
vector<Int_t> pdgCodeID;
pdgCodeID.push_back(    0); // other
pdgCodeID.push_back(   22); // photon
pdgCodeID.push_back(  111); // pi0
pdgCodeID.push_back( -211); // pim
pdgCodeID.push_back(  211); // pip
pdgCodeID.push_back(  221); // eta
pdgCodeID.push_back(  130); // K0L
pdgCodeID.push_back(  310); // K0s
pdgCodeID.push_back( -321); // Km
pdgCodeID.push_back(  321); // Kp
pdgCodeID.push_back(-2112); // (a)n
pdgCodeID.push_back( 2112); // n
pdgCodeID.push_back( 2212); // p
pdgCodeID.push_back( 3122); // Lambda
// ...
```

Now when I compile this (through ROOT, but shouldn't matter), I get the following error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘.’ token
```

for each line corresponding to the `push_back`.

Is this even possible within a header file?
What is going wrong?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You cannot call functions like that outside of functions. You *could* call a function that pushes elements into the vector for you though. But you will have to mark it `static` or `extern`, just like you would any global data. Also, add `std::` where needed in the header. No header should be `using namespace std;`.

Comment: You do know that if you include that header file in multiple source file you will get a multiple definition error on linking?

Comment: Are you calling pdgCodeID.push_back(foo); in the namespace or global context?

Comment: It is very poor practice to have a `using` directive in a header file, as doing so can change the behaviour of other files which include that header (as well as any includes which appear after the directive within the same file).

Comment: It's in one of the standard ROOT header files `Riosfwd.h` (if declared in header) `Riostream.h` if in source. It's not my code; I personally don't like it either, but its the standard in ROOT, take it up with the developers :D.

Comment: @parnmatt You say you don't like the code, but you don't seem too concerned about perpetuating the bad practices yourself. That `vector` needs to be defined in a source file, not a header. MikeSeymour's answer below is the correct one. If using Boost is an option, [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/libs/assign/doc/index.html) should have something that lets you initialize a `vector` with fairly clean syntax.

Comment: @Praetorian, I am still learning ROOT and C++ simultaneously; I'm a Masters student studying Particle Physics, and wondering why such things are not working. I am at the mercy of my tools, and I cannot use Boost::Assign due to CINT seeming to not be compatible.

Comment: I am sure learning ROOT will slow down your C++ learning process considerably, if not bring it to a halt completely. If you want to learn C++, learn it separately, then find a way to work with ROOT (if you *really* have to.)

Comment: On the other hand, I found no `using namespace std;` in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juanchopanza is right, you cannot call functions (like push_back) outside of functions. You are going to have to write a function that initializes the variable like so:

```
//file.h

vector<Int_t> pdgCodeID;

void InitializeCodeID();
```

Then you would need to define the function in the cpp file however you need to initialize the variable. For example:

```
//file.cpp

void InitializeCodeID()
{
    pdgCodeID.push_back(    0); // other
    pdgCodeID.push_back(   22); // photon
    pdgCodeID.push_back(  111); // pi0
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having these in a source file, and to keep said definitions within the header (as I can do with an array).

Comment: Did you check this link? [Get to Know the New C++11 Initialization Forms](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519) On **Introducing C++11 Brace-Initialization**? It is difference from Vlad's answer because it does not have the "=".

Comment: @parnmatt: You can't do that with the array either. You could use `const` or `static` to give it internal linkage, but that's not ideal as you'll end up with duplicate copies in each translation unit that includes the header.

Comment: @JohnOdom I cannot use C++11, as stated in the question. I am limmited to C++98.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I can, as the the first code example (using the array) compiles and works fine, and was edited an modified from one of my supervisors.

Comment: @parnmatt: You can *if* you only include the header from one source file. If you include it from more than one, you'll get a link error due to multiple definitions.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm using header guards, which I've been taught prevents such errors occurring.

Comment: @parnmatt: No, that prevents multiple definitions within one translation unit. It doesn't prevent multiple definitions in different translation units, which is an error if they have external linkage.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't define either in a header, since you'll get a multiple definition error if you include the header in more than one source file. If you really want a global, then declare it in a header:

```
extern std::vector<Int_t> pdgCodeID;  // don't use namespace std
```

and define it in a source file:

```
std::vector<Int_t> pdgCodeID = /* initialiser */;
```

In C++11, that's easy: you can use brace-initialisation just as you do with the array. But since you're not using that for some reason, the best option is probably to initialise it with the result of a function:

```
std::vector<Int_t> make_pdgCodeID() {
    std::vector<Int_t> result;
    result.push_back(0);
    // and so on
    return result;
}

std::vector<Int_t> pdgCodeID = make_pdgCodeID();
```

Alternatively, Boost has a [library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/assign/doc/index.html) for initialising and assigning pre-2011 containers more generically.

Comment: I would want to use C++11 code as it would simplify many of my functions elsewhere. However ROOT uses CINT, which use C++98 (and some C++03 I think), therefore I am limited in that functionality.

Comment: I did look into boost, however CINT seems to have issues with it.

Comment: @parnmatt: It sounds like the library is more trouble than it's worth; but good luck.

Comment: don't get me wrong, it has lots of functionality for data analysis, but written written by and for particle physicist with bad code practises. It's the standard in my field and I have to learn it.

Comment: @parnmatt You can probably go quite a long way without using ROOT. CINT, you really don't need for anything. I survived a long time in your field using it only to make "pretty" pictures, until I figured out how to make them with something else.

Answer (score 2):

You may not use expression statements outside a function. Also it is a bad idea that you placed the vector in a header. You could escape the error if instead of the push_back method you would use initilaizer list. For example

```
vector<Int_t> pdgCodeID = {
        0, // other
       22, // photon
      111, // pi0
     -211, // pim
      211, // pip
      221, // eta
      130, // K0L
      310, // K0s
     -321, // Km
      321, // Kp
    -2112, // (a)n
     2112, // n
     2212, // p
     3122  // Lambda
};
```

Comment: This does not work outside C++11, which I cannot use. It was the first thing I tried.

Comment: You could keep you array as a const array and use it to initialize the vector. For example vector<Int_t> pdgCodeID( YourInitial Array, YourInitialArray + ItsSize );

Comment: Yes this was one of the suggestions I have found else where, but it seemed pointless to create an array to initialise a vector; I wanted it to be dynamic. However this may be the only way to do this.

Comment: It is not pointless if the array contains predefined constants,

Answer (score 0):

No this isn't possible in global scope, you need to do it in a function scope somewhere.

Also, several comments on coding style:

- You shouldn't be using `using namespace std` this is bad coding style, it is only done in textbooks to make examples smaller to better fit on a page of a book. Instead use the std:: specifier for one of uses, declare private types for things you use often, or within a namespace declared by your header, or even within a class use more specific using declarations like `using std::vector`.
- You should't define global variables in a header file, things will explode if the header is included in multiple source files, instead declare the global extern in the header file, and make a source file that defines and initializes the global.

Comment: I am aware it's bad coding practice to have the `using namespace std`, however I have to deal with it as it's in the ROOT framework header files. I'm using header guards, so it wouldn't explode or create redefinition errors.

Comment: What you're doing only protects against multiple inclusions from the same source file, either explicitly or implicitly through indirect includes. What you're not safe from is different source files that both include the same header. Each source file will have it's own copy of the global variable, any changes you make to the global will not be seen by any other source file, and upon linking you may encounter name clashes. Plus it's just wasting memory.